# Update table schema with columns from other table schema

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm working on a data migration tool. When a user adds a field to an entity in the UI, the database schema itself is updated. This is causing havoc when trying to move data.

I currently have a temporary table that contains all the source data, but that temporary table might have extra columns that the destination table doesn't have. Is there some way to update a table schema with the schema from another table (in this case, the temporary table)? There are constraints and indexes on the table, so I can't just select into a new table then rename it into the old table.

I'm working in .NET 4.0 (so no SMO) but SQL solutions are fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using Dynamic SQL for this within a Stored Procedure.

What you'll want to do is figure out the schema of the temp table.  Assuming you create a temp table with the name #nameoftemptable, this should help get you started:

```
SELECT t.name, c.name as colname, types.name, types.max_length
FROM tempdb.sys.tables t 
   JOIN tempdb.sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id
   JOIN sys.types on c.system_type_id = types.system_type_id
WHERE t.name like '#nameoftemptable%'
```

Notice the use of "tempdb" -- this is where temp tables are stored.  This will return you all the columns in the temp table with their data types.

Next you'll need to return the same data for a similar query, but instead of querying tempdb, you'll want to query your db name and your table name:

```
SELECT t.name, c.name as colname, types.name, types.max_length
FROM dbname.sys.tables t 
   join dbname.sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id
   join dbname.sys.types on c.system_type_id = types.system_type_id
where t.name = 'TableName'
```

Now you should be able to compare which columns are new and use the `ALTER TABLE` command accordingly.

Hope this helps and good luck.